# How can I use jquerySelectorAll based on div's style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change all divs of one color to another one. It works with `document.querySelector()` but not with querySelectorAll. I would like to change all of them. Here's my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script >
var v;
var v1;
function link(){
 v1=document.querySelector('[style*="background:black;"]');
 v1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    v=document.querySelectorAll('[style*="background:black;"]');
 v.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background:black; height:100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="background:blue; height:100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="background:black; height:100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="background:black; height:100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="background:blue; height:100px; width:100px;"></div>
<button onclick="link()" style="height:20px; width:50px;">Click </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on what could I do? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for Each, because querySelectorAll will not return you one element

```html
<html>
<head>
<script >
var v;
var v1;
function link(){
 v1=document.querySelector('[style*="background:black;"]');
 v1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    v=document.querySelectorAll('[style*="background:black;"]');
  v.forEach(function(value){
   value.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  })
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background:black; height:100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="background:blue; height:100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="background:black; height:100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="background:black; height:100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="background:blue; height:100px; width:100px;"></div>
<button onclick="link()" style="height:20px; width:50px;">Click </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var v;
var v1;
function link(){

    v=document.querySelectorAll('[style*="background:black;"]');
    for(var j in v){
        if(v[j].style){
            v[j].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
    }
  
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background:black; height:100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="background:blue; height:100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="background:black; height:100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="background:black; height:100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="background:blue; height:100px; width:100px;"></div>
<button onclick="link()" style="height:20px; width:50px;">Click </button>

</body>
</html>
```